# How can I fix package errors when compiling with Play Framework. Getting error: package redis.clients.jedis does not exist

Tags: java, playframework, package, sbt

So I get the following for Jedis in my database class when I try to use the `activator eclipse` command to compile my project after cleaning it :

```
error: package redis.clients.jedis does not exist import redis.clients.jedis.jedis;
```

The jars are on the build path, it doesn't show me any errors in eclipse itself, the unit tests can successfully save data to, and read data from the database.

I figure this is something to do with declaring the packages in a build or config file of some sort for sbt to use, but I'm not sure where I should be looking or what I should be modifying; something in build.sbt perhaps? 
If so, what should I put there? 
This is how build.sbt looks at the moment:

```
name := """myApp"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt doesn't know where to find the dependency. Add this line to your `build.sbt` within `libraryDependencies`:

```
"redis.clients" % "jedis" % "2.6.0"
```